# Suspend not working after upgrade to 16.04

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, suspend

I have been an Ubuntu user for 10 years.  I run a dual boot system with the latest LTS version and the latest version on the same machine on separate hard drives.  Until recently I had 14.04 and 15.10 running with no problems.  A few weeks ago, I upgraded 14.04 to 16.04.  There was a 15.10 update at about the same time.  Since then neither version will suspend and wake up.  After suspend, the wake up key causes a hard restart.  There have not been any hardware changes.  Does anyone have any advice?  Leaving the machine on 24/7 is not a desirable position, nor is shutting down after each session.

There used to be a regular problem with suspend on all versions, but it was corrected somewhere around 2014.